# vertex input from storage buffer performance

Tags: vulkan

Are there any performance penalties in getting vertex data from a storage buffer, instead of using a vertex buffer and setting up a regular vertex input state?

Is there any reason why it should be avoided?

Comment: Unanswerable without measuring all drivers in existence. Probably a bad idea though. I do not see any benefit in using storage buffers for it.

Comment: @krOoze: There are benefits to implementing your own vertex pulling. You can make your data more compact, depending on what the data actually is.

Comment: I suppose; still sounds hacky. Storage buffer is random access thing. Vertex buffer is localized thing. There's some tradeoff here for sure. Anyway AIS you would have to measure. Future-wise, all of this will probably get replaced by `VK_NV_mesh_shader` extension anyway...

Comment: @krOoze: I have the same feeling, there must be a tradoff of some kind, but I can't measure every driver.

Comment: Yea, nobody can. Compared 1:1, vertex buffer is probably better or same, otherwise the feature would not exist. But under @NicolBolas premise if you could take one byte off of storage buffer and generate trillion triangles from it, then that would probably be better. And you have not even specified to what ratio your storage buffer would be smaller to regular vertex buffer. Anyway here it goes, the pointless speculation the StackOverflow policy tries to avoid.

Comment: @krOoze I was indeed hoping for some unknown benchmark or guide proving it was a terrible idea, but as I suspected, there is none. Should be closed.